# Windows Explorer software that auto-rename files in ascending order

Tags: windows-explorer

Suppose I have a folder that contain the following files:

```
001.jpg
002.jpg
003.jpg
004.jpg
005.jpg
```

After delete the file 002.jpg in a "Windows Explorer" software, the "Windows Explorer" software will automatically rename the files as follows:

```
001.jpg
003.jpg => rename to 002.jpg
004.jpg => rename to 003.jpg
005.jpg => rename to 004.jpg
```

Are there such "Windows Explorer" (or similar file manager) that offered such features?

Comment: There are myriad file rename tools out there, but none which I'm aware of that will perform this function automatically. Though perhaps something like AutoHotKey might be the answer.

Comment: I am about to hit the sack but Powershell might be able to do this. If no one solves this by tomorrow morning I'll look at it more closely.

Comment: @Paperlantern, Hope to hear from you soon.

Comment: @jack Sorry man this one fell off my radar completely, thanks for the reminder, I'll tinker with it some today.

Comment: @Jack Is this a one time deal, or is this something you want to do as a rolling job? Like every time you delete one of the files, the rest get renamed in order to match up?

Comment: @Paperlantern, it is like a background job that do polling such that every time I delete one of the files, the rest get renamed in order to match up.

Answer (score 1):

Read this on [How-To Geek](http://www.howtogeek.com). I think it may do the trick! I did a test on my computer and it worked as advertised.

> If you want to sequentially rename files really fast in Windows 7, all
>   you have to do is highlight all of them and hit F2 to rename them. Name the first
>   one and hit enter. The files will be renamed somename (1).ext and so
>   on. It’s really handy for bulk renaming vacation photos and what not.